# Angularjs Get innerWidth

Tags: angularjs, resize, width

I would like to have the innerWidth of my browser in my controller. I found a directive that outputs the width on the screen, but i would like to have it in my controller. My ng-repeat depends on the width of the screen. The directive that I found is:

```
app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
return function (scope) {
    scope.width = $window.innerWidth;
    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.width = $window.innerWidth;
        });
    });
};
});
```

So my question is, how can i get the innerWidth of my browser in my controller and let it update it self whenever the browser resizes?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Why don't you just inject `$window` into your controller and use it? I posted a solution

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$window` into your controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$window', '$scope', function($window, $scope) {
    // Do whatever you want with $window now
    // For instance, $window.innerWidth would return the inner width.
}]);
```

Comment: But  does it updates it self? because it depends on the width of the browser how many rows i split my ng-repeat

Comment: What do you mean? What updates itself? As for splitting, you really should use a responsive front-end framework like Foundation or Bootstrap. They will take care of those things for you. I think it is a terrible idea to do it yourself using the `$window.innerWidth`